# Не могу импортировать longpoll из vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

***Ошибка:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 6, in <module>
    from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPol, VkEventType
ImportError: cannot import name 'VkLongPol' from 'vk_api.longpoll'
```

***Код:***

```py
import random 
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = '...')

from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPol, VkEventType

longpoll = VkLongPol(vk_session)

vk = vk_session.get_api()

global Random 

def random_id():
    Random = 0
    Random += random.randint(0, 10000000)
    return Random

while true:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
            if event.text.lower() == 'привет':
                vk.messeg.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'Привет!',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас сразу несколько ошибок в коде:

1. Вы пытаетесь импортировать неопределённый класс `VkLongPol`. Но я не буду заострять на этом внимание, потому что он Вам вообще не нужен.

Вы авторизуетесь по ключу сообщества, поэтому должны использовать модуль `vk_api.bot_longpoll`.

2. Вы не передаёте параметр `group_id` при подключении к
   `longPoll` серверу.
3. Вы пытаетесь вызвать несуществующий метод `API` — `messeg.send`.
   Скорее всего, Вы опечатались и имели в виду `messages.send`.

---

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


def main() -> None:
    vk_session = VkApi(token='[token]')
    long_poll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '[group_id]')
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    for event in long_poll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']
            message = event.obj['text'].lower()

            if message == 'привет':
                vk.messages.send(
                    peer_id=peer_id,
                    message='Привет!',
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Не забудьте заменить `[token]` и `[group_id]` на свои значения!*

---

Данный код отвечает на сообщение `привет` в любом регистре аналогичным `Привет!`.

Хотелось бы отметить то, что я использую `peer_id` для отправки сообщений. Это универсальный идентификатор, который позволяет отвечать как в беседах, так и в ЛС.

Костыль `random_id()` я заменил аналогичной функцией `vk_api.utils.get_random_id`.

Также данный код, в отличие от Вашего, следует стандартам `PEP-8`.