# В чем ошибка кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
import vk_api
import time
import random
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = "some token goes here...")
vk._auth_token()
uch = []
while  True:
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations",{"offaet": 0, "count": 1})
    if messages["count"] >=1:
         id = messages["items"][0]["conversation"]["peer"]["id"]
         body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
         chat = messages["items"][0]["conversation"]["peer"]["type"]
         typ = messages["items"][0]["conversation"]["peer"]["type"]
         id_own = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
         if typ == "chat":
            if "Луи" in body.lower():
                if id_own == 472427950:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                else:
                    if "кто" in body.lower():
                        opred = vk.method("messages.getConversationaMembers", {"peer_id": id})
                        count = opred["count"]
                        for i in range(count):
                            first_name = opred["profiels"][1]["first_name"]
                            last_name = opred["profiels"][1]["last_name"]
                            peer = opred["profiels"][1]["id"]
                            message = "И этот человек:"+"id"+str(peer.id)+"("+first_name+")"
                            uch.append(message)
                        mes = random.choice(uch)
                        vk.method("message.send",{"peer_id":id,"message":mes})
                    elif  "Определи" in body.lower() or "Сколько" in body.lower():
                        random_choice = random.randrange(1,100,1)
                        vk.method("message.send", {"peer_id":id, "message":str(random_choice)+"%"})
                    elif "правда" in body.lower():
                        s = ["Да", "Нет"]
                        mesage = random.choise(s)
                        vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id":id, "message":mesage})
```

Бот ни на что не реагирует в беседе.

Comment: пишите код внимательно и читайте документацию, тогда не будет таких глупых ошибок.

Comment: Я прямо сейчас всё перечитываю, и прислушался к вам, заменил код, но ничего всё равно не работает  @n1tr0xs

Comment: Может, Вы израсходовали лимит запросов? У Вас в коде бесконечный цикл. Он вполне может посылать больше 20 запросов в секунду. Да и вообще, Вы получаете сообщения **ооочень** странным образом. Для этого Вы должны использовать `longPoll API` или `Callback API`

Comment: @nomnoms12 я раньше с Django, и не разу с Vk_api, я читал документацию, но ничего особенно не понимаю, может есть книги, или другие источники где обучают как с этим работать?

Comment: @ВадимЩербаков [Пример с longPoll API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1017220/339283), [пример с Django + Callback API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1065421/339283).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations",{"offaet": 0, "count": 1})
```

на

```
messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations",{"offset": 0, "count": 1})
```